# Presenting a collection view as a subview works, but presenting it by a collection view controller fails when a cell should be dequeued

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I set up a collection view programmatically:
I have 2 properties synthesized:

```
@property (strong) IconCollectionViewController *collectionViewController;
@property (strong) UICollectionView *collectionView;
```

and later :

```
    // Create a layout for the collection view
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];

    // Create the collection view
    self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"IconCell"];

    // Create a collection view controller, and link it with the collection view
    self.collectionViewController  = [[IconCollectionViewController alloc] initWithCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
    self.collectionView.delegate   = self.collectionViewController;
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self.collectionViewController;
    self.collectionViewController.collectionView = self.collectionView;
```

Further, the collection view controller implements the required protocols:

```
@interface IconCollectionViewController () <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>
```

If I present the collection view as a subview, everything works well:

```
[self.view addSubview:collectionView];
```

But I cannot present it using the newly set up collection view controller:

```
[self presentViewController:self.collectionViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

In this case, I get the error message

```
 *** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView  
    _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:],  
/SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2380.17/UICollectionView.m:2249
```

in the data source callback when I try to dequeue a cell

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"IconCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}
```

Can somebody explain why presenting the collection view as a subview works, and presenting it using the collection view controller fails when a cell should be dequeued? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, but I am not happy with it.
First I simplified my code. When I set up the collection view controller, I now only create the layout and the controller, and then present it. This is possible according to the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewController_clas/Reference/Reference.html), "*If you create the collection view controller programmatically, it automatically creates a new unconfigured collection view object, which you can access using the collectionView property.*"
I assumed that I can access the `collectionView` property of the collection view controller already in the `viewDidLoad` method of this controller, but this is not the case. Apparently, the first time I can access it is in the data source callback `collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:` which gives me the actually used `collectionView` object. Therefore I can only there register my `collectionViewCell` class with the cell identifier using

```
[view registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:myCellID];
```

If done this way, everything works fine.
But I am sure it is not the right way to register the cell class, but I don't know where to do it earlier and only once.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same problem although this might be very old, you can present the CollectionViewController by registering the cells from the first view controller before presenting it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Actually, I am no longer able to check your suggestion... This is too long ago. Maybe somebody else can check it?